# Program status via Thinc API

Tags: okuma

How can I get program status such as interrupted, stopped, in progress, waiting, aborted and so on via Thinc API? There is nothing similar to it in CProgram of Okuma.CLDATAPI.DataAPI and Okuma.CMDATAPI.DataAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Lathe API >= 1.9.1 or on a mill API >= 1.12.1 (I think) you can use the `CMachine.GetNCStatus function`

```
Public Function GetNCStatus(ByVal enNCStatus As NCStatusEnum) As OnOffStateEnum
```

Pass in the status you wish to check and this function will return to you a Boolean err I mean an On or Off from the OnOffStateEnum

The NCStatusEnum members:

- Program Stop: M00, M01
- STM:  Waiting on M-code, spindle acceleration, or Tool Change
- SlideHold: Slide hold button was pushed
- Limit: X,Z axes are at their variable limit position
- Alarm: Indicates that machine is an alarm condition
- Run: The machine is actually operating in the Automatic or MDI mode.

In earlier versions of the API some of the same states could be tested by checking I/O bits.